# .Net Common collection which can be shared among the applications

Tags: design-patterns

I need to implement common collection service for easy and fast searching.
It should also be shared among the multiple applications.

Common collections will be managed by applications and concurrency must be maintained.

Kindly suggest me the best way to implement this in .net application
and the pattern which should I follow with some minor example.

Comment: What do you mean collection service or common collections? .NET already has many collections, many of them thread-safe. If you want many applications to use common data though, use a database. There's no pattern to answer this question - the question is too confusing.

Comment: I mean to say that I have several applications load key value pairs from DB to avoid frequent DB operation. I just keep frequently required things in that key value pairs. currently it is duplicated in all c# application instances. I want to create separate service which hold the key values and all applications uses that service to search data and avoid data duplication. As my application is too much dependent on performance and this key values pairs which I loaded contains millions of records and query this collections even more than that, That's why I am searching for proper method to do it.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for Redis.

Comment: Yes Exactly, I have even tried memcache but the storing .net object converted to JSON  in memcache but take a lot of time for serialization & deserialization.

Comment: Then that's the problem. Instead of storing values, you try to serialize entire objects. If you don't use a fast Json serializer like Json.NET this can get a lot worse. Just don't do that.In fact, I'm starting to suspect that the database isn't a problem either but some inefficient serialization or ORM query